# Очередь запросов (todo list) в Symfony через RabbitMQ

Tags: php, ubuntu, symfony, rabbitmq

Linux. Хотел увидеть, статус моих сообщений, дошли ли они или не дошли. Для этого нужно открыть страницу RabbitMQ. Пишу в своей консоли

```
 symfony open:local:rabbitmq
```

Но ответ таков:   RabbitMQ management not found
Ничего не помогло, даже переустановка symfony, rabbitMQ

Comment: скорее всего у вас какой-то пакет недоподключен. Проверьте доки симфы

Answer (score 0):

Данная команда описана в документации Symfony, в разрезе интеграции с Docker-ом, подробнее [тут](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#docker-integration). Добавление [RabbitMQ в Docker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/ru/32-rabbitmq.html).

Если вы все сделали верно, по документации, советую попробовать выполнить вашу команду в контейнере с приложением:

```
sudo docker ps
// Далее, увидите список поднятых контейнеров, вам нужен Symfony
sudo docker exec -it здесь_название_или_hash_контейнера sh
symfony open:local:rabbitmq
```